# All scaled combination of vector elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I have a vector like this:

```
 A=[3 4 5 6];
```

I would like obtain a new Matrix B which is composed by all possible scaled combination of A elements avoiding rows with only one element (then at least two elements for each row), for instance:

```
B=[3 4 5 6;
   3 4 5 0;
   3 4 0 0;
   0 4 5 6;
   0 0 5 6;
   3 0 5 6;
   3 0 5 0;
   0 0 5 6;
   3 4 0 6;
   0 4 0 6;
   3 4 0 0;
   etc...  
];
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "scaled"?

Comment: the term should be clear reading the example

Comment: From the example, it seems that the term "scaled" should be removed altogeher. Else, I have no clue what it means here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
A = [3 4 5 6]; % data
N = 2; % minimum number of elements that should be present
p = dec2bin(1:2^numel(A)-1)-'0'; % binary pattern. Each row is a combination
s = sum(p,2)>=N; % index to select rows of p that have at least N ones
result = bsxfun(@times, A, p(s,:)); % multiply with singleton expansion
```

This gives, in your example,

```
result =
     0     0     5     6
     0     4     0     6
     0     4     5     0
     0     4     5     6
     3     0     0     6
     3     0     5     0
     3     0     5     6
     3     4     0     0
     3     4     0     6
     3     4     5     0
     3     4     5     6
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot